# CSS Border Size Color

Tags: html, css

I made my left border width greater, and there is black instead of my text's background color (Screenshot and Code below).

[image: result]

I already tried:

```
background-size: 80px 60px;
```

I want it to remain as the text background color (rest of navbar).

HTML:

```
<a href="url" id="homelink">home</a>
<!-- hompage link -->
<a href="url" id="projectslink">projects</a>
<!-- link naar projects pagina -->
<a href="url" id ="gameslink">games</a>
<!-- linkinaar games pagina -->
<h1 id="h1index"> welcom to the codenoob website </h1>
<!-- welcom message -->
<p id="tekstindex">latest news.</p>
```

CSS:

```
#h1index {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#F2F2F2,#94A394);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

#tekstindex {
color: black;
}

#homelink {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#F2F2F2,#94A394);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent black black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-left-width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: And where's the code you're talking about?

Comment: What do you want to make bigger? The green background? Try: padding:10px; want to change the color of the border? Try: border-color:red;

Comment: @Paules I think he's talking about the "Home" button...

Comment: Post your code. Tag me.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mxj3dhKT @DaniSpringer.com

Comment: Post it in the question. As little as necessary of it.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#homelink {
    border-left-width: 15px;
}
```

To this:

```
#homelink {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j5157mc0/